# How long should someone wait to apply for a secured credit card after having been deliquent on a loan payment?

Tags: credit-card, loans, credit-score, secured-credit-card

Someone failed to make payments on a college loan for an extensive period (8-10 months). Their credit score has, as a result, dropped to 550-575. They have since paid off their overdue balance and have resumed making regular, on-time payments. Now the person wants to begin rebuilding their credit score.

How long should the person wait to apply for a secured credit card, such as the [Discover it Secured Credit Card](https://www.discover.com/credit-cards/secured/)?

**EDIT:** To clarify, my concern is that the application will be rejected based on the recent delinquency. My understanding is that can happen, potentially resulting in a hard inquiry on the credit report without successfully obtaining the card.

Comment: On a damaged credit profile, hard inquiries are the least of your worries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sooner one starts to rebuild, the faster it will go. So once everything is caught up, they should immediately start working on the rebuild. The Discover card is a great one to begin with.

Comment: My concern is that the application will be rejected based on the recent delinquency. My understanding is that can happen, resulting in a hard inquiry on the credit report.

Comment: I opened a secured Discover card a few days after my BK was discharged - the most recent delinquency was less than 6 months old.

Comment: If you open an account with State Department Credit Union, their secured card does not even do a credit check.

Comment: The application for the "Discover it" card ended up being **immediately approved** online, despite only 3 months since delinquency and only **one month of on-time payments _reported_ since delinquency**. Of course, your mileage may vary depending on salary and many other factors. Thanks for the words, everyone.